# about Session.rollBack() in JMS

Tags: jms

All, 
  i am new to JMS and i have a question about *Session.rollBack()* method in JMS. AFAIK, this method is used to roll back all operations to JMS server (sending/receiving) by the session when using *SESSION_TRANSACTED* acknowledge mode. Now suppose I am calling this method in a catch block of a receiving/processing operation (is reasonable?), to tell JMS server to redeliver the message for processing, But even if it is redelivered the processing still throws the same exception which cause the JMS server to redeliver the message again, so it seems a infinite process. How to handle this problem? or are there any other JMS features that is designed for it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The rollback method in JMS will rollback any message sends and receives in that "transaction". Transaction here is local to the JMS session.

Whether a redelivery will cause a problem really depends on why the exception occurred. If it was due to some transitory issue then a redelivery may work. If you have the kind of problem that is once it occurs will always occur (an example of this would be a JMS TextMessage whose body should contain XML, but doesn't).

The JMS API doesn't provide any solution to this itself. This is typically taken care of by the JMS provider and how it behaves will depend on which one you use. WebSphere MQ for instance will redeliver up to a configurable maximum at which point it will move it off to a queue for bad messages. The Service Integration Bus in WebSphere Application Server has similar behaviour. I suggest you consult your JMS provider documentation to determine exactly how it behaves in this situation.

If you are running in an application server rollback typically doesn't do anything because the application server will be managing transactions for you.